# A body is floating in a liquid of equal density and then pushed down. Why does it sink?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics, buoyancy

> A body is just floating on the surface of a liquid. The density of the body is the same as that of the liquid. The body is slightly pushed down. What will happen to the body?
>
> (A) It will slowly come back to its earlier position
> (B) It will remain submerged, where it is left
> **(C) It will sink**
> (D) It will come out violently

My answer to this question is (B), because if the densities of the body and liquid are equal, the body is always in equilibrium when it is completely submerged. So it should remain wherever it is left.

But the answer given is (C). I don't understand why the body would sink in the liquid when its density is not more than the liquid's. Why will the body sink?

Comment: Think about what the slight push downwards causes, and what will be the result after the push stops.

Comment: 'slightly' is somewhat ambiguous. Also, drag force on the descending object needs to be considered. But C would be my answer.

Comment: The question is ambiguous.  The answer could just as easily be "B".

Comment: I made the title more specific.

Answer (score 2):

> My answer to this question is (B), because if the densities of the
> body and liquid are equal, the body is always in equilibrium when it
> is completely submerged. So it should remain wherever it is left.

It will not remain submerged at the position wherever it is left (which I assume means at the point where the push stops) because the push causes some initial acceleration downward giving it an initial velocity and movement downward. In other words, it will sink.

How far it sinks is another question. The problem with answer (C) which may lead to confusion, is "sinking" normally refers to the case where the density of the body is greater than the fluid. In this case the densities are the same. After the push ends, since the buoyant force equals the force of gravity on the body, the only net force acting on the body will be the water drag force acting upward. That force is proportional to the square of the velocity downward, and will cause the body to decelerate until it stops at some final position below the surface.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice, clear answer.

Comment: @JohnDarby Thanks John.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the correct answer is (C). It will sink.

First, try to do the experiment by yourself. You will see that the body will sink when pushed.

**Explanation:-**

It all comes down to upthrust. The liquid exerts an upward force (upthrust) equal in magnitude to the weight of the volume of liquid displaced by the body.

The body is floating in an equilibrium state because the upthrust cancels the downward force of the weight and the net force is null.

Thus, when an external force is applied on the body in the downward direction, its downward-direction force increases and the net effect is non-zero.

Since, the net effect is in the downwards direction, the body will ***sink***. If the force is then removed, it will return to its original position.